# Checkbox values should be true/false instead of on/off

Tags: extjs

I m new into Extjs. I m trying to get the value of checked/unchecked checkbox as (boolean) true/false instead of (string) "on"/"off".

Is there any way around to achieve this?

Value being called in C# as

```
string male = context.Request.Form.Get("maleCheckbox");
```

and the ExtJs i m using is:

```
xtype: 'checkbox',
fieldLabel: 'Male',
name: 'maleCheckbox'
```

However to achieve this manually, I wrote a lot of if/else statements but I m looking for some efficient alternative.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `inputValue` and `uncheckedValue`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)

Comment: contemplating copying Evan's comment as an answer to score the 'accepted answer' ;)